# Need to change background color of current link

Tags: html, css

I have my navbar of links and when the user is on a page that corresponds to one of the links I want to change the background color of that link. For example, when the user is on the home page I want to change the background color of the home link. I tried with #navbar li a:current but that doesn't work.Is this possible with css?

html:

```
<div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="samples.html">Samples</a></li>                
            </ul>            
        </div> <!-- end of navbar div -->
```

CSS:

```
#navbar li a.current {
background-color: #FFF;}
```

Comment: I believe you'll need some language on the backend to determine which page you're currently on and apply a special class to one of the `<li>` elements in the navbar.

Comment: What technology/framwork are you using?

Comment: I'm just going to leave this as a comment since I'm sure there is a better way to accomplish this, but you could either give an `id` to each nav and include the `background-color` css for that nav only in it's respective html file, or you could use in-line css on the targeted element in each html file. Obviously both options require you to break away from a single, global css file and would eliminate any transitions (ie fading in and out or sliding animations) but this will, at a basic level, change the background color based on what page the user is on.

Comment: You'll need some javascript or backend code to set a class on the active nav item based on the page that's currently being displayed.

Comment: You'll need to use either a back-end script/language ([tag:php], [tag:ruby], [tag:asp.net], etc) or a client-side script ([tag:javascript]) in order to accomplish this. CSS has no means of determining what the 'current' page is.

Comment: framwork??? I'm using dreamweaver html5. Not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Joe Elmore See my answer below.

Comment: @Stano he wants the background to be white when your on the page that corresponds to the link, not when hovering over the link.

Comment: @JoeElmore you updated your code above, did that fix the issue for you on your site?

Comment: @disinfor  That still doesn't work. I think it's like some are saying, the css can't determine what the current page is. I think it will have to be done with javascript but unfortunately I don't even know how to include javascript on a webpage.

Comment: Yes Joe, you must determine and add the `class="current"` attribute on server (either to the `li` or the `a` tag).

Comment: I fixed my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is wrong. It should be `#navbar li a.current {
background-color: #FFF;}` You had a colon after `a:current`.

Your HTML should be like this:

```
<div id="navbar"><ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="samples.html">Samples</a></li>                
            </ul>            
        </div> <!-- end of navbar div -->
```

Comment: But you're assuming there is a "current" class on the current page's "li" element, which in the OP there is not.

Comment: Ahh..my brain filled that in. I'll adjust my answer. Considering the site isn't dynamic, the update would work. (He also fixed the error in the code above).

Comment: This works using css #navbar li.current { background-color: #FFF;}         Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="samples.html">Samples</a></li>                
        </ul>            
    </div> <!-- end of navbar div -->
```

Now create a background color for the class of "current". You'll have to apply that class with the backend logic. CSS cannot workout the logic by itself. It only handles the styles

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using Javascript/JQuery (although a server-side approach is probably better):

```
var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
var pageName = currentPath.substr(currentPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // "index.html", etc
$("a[href=" + pageName + "]").parent().css("background", "#FFF");
```

The above requires JQuery, but you can do something similar in pure Javascript:

```
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('a[href=' + pageName + ']');
if (targets.length > 0) {
    targets[0].parentNode.style.background = "#FFF";
}
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8zuEe/3/)

Comment: Well, strictly-speaking, jQuery certainly is JavaScript. It does, however, require the jQuery library. You really should mention that.

Comment: His CSS is wrong (that's the main issue). I don't think he's trying to do it dynamically, but this solution could work. I have a PHP solution I use on almost every non-CMS site I do. Create a variable for the page and then write an `if` statement to call a class if the visitor is on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript(jQuery) like this:

```
var currenturl = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
$('#navbar>li>a[href="'+currenturl[1]+'"]').css({background: 'some_color'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish this only with CSS, maybe you can use the parent's IDs:

```
<div id="parent1">
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="service"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="sample"><a href="samples.html">Samples</a></li>                
        </ul>            
    </div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="service"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="sample"><a href="samples.html">Samples</a></li>                
        </ul>            
    </div>
</div>
```

And then...

```
#parent1 li.home {
    background: red;
}
#parent2 li.home {
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse it is possible with pure css3. You could give an id to all your 'li' s.
like ,
  li id="sample"

then modify your anchor to 
  a href="index.html#sample"

use CSS :target selector

li:target{
   // apply your styles here 
   }

simple